# sortable input is not working in r shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

i created small app in which if i click button it should render a sortble UI , and it should show me selected input as well in UI but somehow UI rendering is working fine but i am not able to get input from sortable , here's my code below, this is after observeEvent after clicking button

```r
sortable_labels_an <- input$select_analysis
sortable_labels_an <- unlist(sortable_labels_an)
sortable_labels_an <- paste(sortable_labels_an, collapse=",")
sortable_list_an <- rank_list(
  text = "Drag Analysis in desired order",
  labels = sortable_labels_an,
  input_id = "sorable_list_an"
)
output$sortable_an <- renderUI({
        sortable_list_an
})
selected_analysis <- as.list(input$sorable_list_an)
print(selected_analysis)
```

here's print result i am getting :-

```r
list()
```

i want to print selected sortable as input like :-

```r
input$sortable_list_an
```

````
library(sortable)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("test_sel","select",choices = c("jav",
                                              "new2",
                                              "NEW1",
                                              "eon",
                                              "Mum"), multiple = T),
  actionButton("add","create_group"),
  uiOutput("sortable")
)

# server.R ----
server <- function(input, output,session) {
  observeEvent(input$add,{
    list1 <- NULL
    selected <- input$test_sel
    arr<-array(unlist(selected))
    arr <- paste(arr, collapse=",")
    sorable_list <- as.list(arr)
    sorable_list <- rank_list(
      text = "Drag Curves in desired order",
      labels = sorable_list,
      input_id = "sorable_list"
    )
    output$sortable <- renderUI({
      sorable_list})
    
    testing <- input$sorable
    print(testing)
  })
}

# Run the app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)```
```print(testing)```

```NULL```
added new example code for recreating issue
````

Comment: It's not clear if `sortable_labels_an <- input$select_analysis` takes place inside a `reactive`/`observe` block. If it doesn't, then ... it should. Is it possible to include a minimum working shiny app that reproduces your problem?

Comment: If all of this is within another observe/reactive block, then ... I've not yet see a situation where having a `renderUI` (or any `render$` or reactive/observe) nested inside another made sense to me or was strictly necessary.

Comment: `sortable_labels_an <- input$select_analysis` takes place inside one observeEvent

Comment: so basically `sortable_labels_an <- input$select_analysis` have multiple entries for example `A,B,C` as list and it is creating individual entries in sortable , but i wanted those entries as one entry in sortable . thats why i am unlisting and adding comma .  its also showing me on UI . but when i am trying to take input$sortable then its not giving me any values which is getting displayed on UI

Comment: So you're saying that all of the code in your first code block is within an `observeEvent`? If so, is there a reason you are nesting it?

Comment: It's easier to help if you provide a [reproducible shiny example](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/wiki/Creating-a-Reproducible-Example). The code should be complete enough so we can copy/paste into R for testing. It's really hard to help when we have to guess what the context might be.

Comment: @r2evans i have added one code snippet which is replica of what i want to achieve , nesting what? i didnt get u sir, also issue is while printing input$sortble it is giving me null value also , i am creating it as array as i want all selected inputs from select input as one entry in sortable UI

Comment: @MrFlick i have added code snippet for reproduction . i hope it helps , also issue is while printing input$sortble it is giving me null value

Comment: "nested" means you have a reactive component (`renderUI`) _inside_ of another reactive component (`observeEvent`). I've never see a need or benefit from it, and while I'm not an all-might-shiny-guru, nobody has countered me or demonstrated when it would work in a specific way that not-nested cannot also achieve.

Comment: @r2evans i added (renderUI) inside observerEvent because when (selectInput) is selecting some items from its choices its making list out of it , so on UI i have one button after clicking that button that list is getting converted to one single string with commas, and then i am using  render UI to display that string on sortable UI as sortable item .

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't nest reactive components, put most of your code inside the `renderUI`.
2. You said it is producing a comma-separated list, but it's *your code* that's doing that. When I debug and look at `input$test_sel`, it's a vector. Let's just work with that.

```r
library(sortable)
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("test_sel", "select", 
              choices = c("jav", "new2", "NEW1", "eon", "Mum"),
              multiple = TRUE),
  actionButton("add", "create_group"),
  uiOutput("sortable")
)
server <- function(input, output,session) {
  output$sortable <- renderUI({
    req(input$add)
    selected <- isolate(input$test_sel)
    rank_list(
      text = "Drag Curves in desired order",
      labels = selected,
      input_id = "sorable_list"
    )
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: working shiny sortable]

Comment: creating select input list as comma separated is my motive

Comment: Okay, then ... (1) `unlist` is not needed, `selected` is already a vector; and (2) why have a "sortable" that is a length-1 string of comma-delimited selections? I'm confused ... but please help me to understand!

Comment: so thing is :- when i do selection from select input it is selecting for example three values like :- 
1) Value 1,
2) Value 2,
3) value 3

now i am converting that into one string like :- 1) Value 1, Value 2, Value 3 because in sortable i want 1) Value 1, Value 2, Value 3 as first entry . then i will select more entries so my sortable input should look like this :- 
1) Value 1, Value 2, Value 3
2) Value4 , Value 5, Value 6

Comment: that's a better explanation ... you need another data structure to "capture" a current set of things into a single element for your `sortable`; I see none of that in your question, please edit it to add that context and perhaps a quick walk-through to make sure I understand correctly

Comment: how do you propose to give the user the ability to "remove" a set once added? you need a collection with "add" and "remove" methods